# Jquery Change ajaxSource Variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How can I change a variable in the below path:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#panel').slidePanel({
    triggerName: '#trigger',
    position: 'absolute',
    triggerTopPos: '180px',
    ajax: true,
    ajaxSource: 'list.php?t=type&aid=<?php echo "$AID"; ?>',
    clickOutsideToClose: false
    });
    .............
```

Upon users input?

If there are two buttons and each one sets variable 'type' to something different.  Is this possible after page loads?

Comment: Oh yes, it is possible.

Comment: I think that *slidePanel* must have some function to change the values of its variables. So, if it is the case, you just have to call this method when the button is clicked. Please, try to check if this function exists or edit your question adding a link to the *slidePanel* documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In general you would something like this

```
var t = $('#buttonID').val();

{
    ajaxSource: 'list.php?t=' + t + '&aid=$var',
}
```

but you will have to post more code for me to figure out what you are trying to do.

Edit:

I am not familiar with slide panel. So I am not 100% sure if putting its init function inside of a button click event will work the way you want.  However this should solve the issue with setting the variable in the url.

```
var aid = '<?php echo $var; ?>';
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.buttonClass').click(function() {
         var t = $(this).data('id');
         var url = "list.php?t=" + t + "&aid=" + aid;
         $('#panel').slidePanel({
             triggerName: '#trigger',
             position: 'absolute',
             triggerTopPos: '180px',
             ajax: true,
             ajaxSource: url,
             clickOutsideToClose: false
         });
    });
});
```

Then your buttons should look something like this

```
<button class=".buttonClass" data-id="1" >button 1</button>
<button class=".buttonClass" data-id="2" >button 2</button>
```

Comment: sorry yeah I was in my rendered and didnt grab it all.  I updated it from the actual. I was trying something like you mentioned but not exactly to no avail.

Comment: ok, you are mixing php with javascript. The code I posted in my answer is only js and won't work for what you are trying to do.  Although it is possible and also easy to combine php and javascript.  It usually isn't necessary.  If you post the relevant html of your buttons that you mentioned and also the php from the page that has this doc ready.  That would be helpful

Comment: No, yeah I understand.  I am looking into rewriting the entire piece.  The "aid" variable -> $var is something that is passed in from php, the "t" was something that I was wondering about being interactive on the page, where the user makes a choice.  I have restructured it like above now...  and just trying to change "type" via jquery button.

Comment: ok, see the edits I just made to my post.  Hopefully that will help you.

Comment: Interesting way of going about it...  un memento, this might be the ticket!

Comment: Nope.  Thanks though.  It started acting up all funky.  I am gonna look at another way and rewrite.  Thanks again.